# CSS3 Animation trigger on viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My idea is of triggering this border-bottom transition animation on my h2 element when it appears in the viewport.

Now, I made it work in JSFiddle, with jQuery 1.7.2, but for whatever reason it doesn't work in the newest jQuery.

Here is the working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/M2RzU/209/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.underline').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {

  if (visible == true) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
    $(this).addClass('full');
      console.log( "added ");
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
     $(this).removeClass('full');
       console.log( "removed ");
  }
});
```

});

And here is the not working one on codepen and jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4645L2md/

Any idea why it's not working ?

Comment: What happens if you replace `bind(` with `on(` ?

Comment: @ErikPhilips was trying the same but doesn't work, nor it throws any error

Comment: The other fiddle uses an external resource js and yours doesn't.

Comment: If you add the external JS file to the Fiddle, [you will start getting errors](http://jsfiddle.net/yzrzu8uz/). Looks like [the plugin does not support jQuery 2](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview/issues/26).

Comment: That's the whole problem, seems like this the only solution to add this transition when it is in viewport but it does not work, dunno what else I could think off to make it work.